# installing redis server on an ec2 instance where postgres is installed

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql, redistributable

I have an ec2 microinstance. I have installed only my postgressql database server over there. 
I want to try redis for celery backend and also for some realtime value storing.

I am expecting as of now a traffic of 5k users during the day.

Is it a good idea for me to ahead, and install redis server on the same ec2 instance?